# Why am I author of message send by byt - python discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to send discord message to channel using python bot, but when I print it's author, it's me and not the bot. So later I can't edit it because of the author.

How can I send message as the bot?

My function:

```
@bot.command(name="send")
async def send(ctx: Context) -> None:
    message = "message"
    await ctx.channel.send(message)
    print(ctx.message.author)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ctx.message` is the message that **invoked the command**, not the message sent by the bot... So `ctx.message.author` is the person that invoked the command, which is you.

```py
print(ctx.message.author)  # <- "print the author of the message that invoked this command"
```

When you use `Messageable.send()`, it returns the message it sent. Thus, `ctx.channel.send()` returns the message that it sends. The `.author` of *that* message is your bot, and *that* is the message you can edit.

```py
message = await ctx.channel.send("something")
```

Answer (score 1):

**I should mention I'm using a wrapper called pycord which I highly recommend.**

**member.id** (Shows the specified members id)

**member.name** (Shows the specified members name and #)

**member.mention** (Mentions the specified member)

Doing **ctx.send** will show only the bot's message but will show a error code at the same time, So use **ctx.respond("whatever")** instead.

**ctx.channel.send** will send to a channel is

**channel.send** will send to a specified channel

Comment: ? ``ctx.member`` doesn't exist, ``ctx.respond`` doesn't exist either, and ``ctx.channel.send`` doesn't require you to specify a channel - ``ctx.channel`` _is_ the channel

Comment: Sorry I thought this was a given, you put await in front ctx.respond i never said ctx.member by itself, ctx.channel.send sometimes does depending on what your doing,

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're on about. It's not about "putting await in front of `ctx.respond`", I'm saying that that method **literally doesn't exist** so you can't even `await` it if you wanted to. And you never said `ctx.member` by itself, but saying `ctx.member.X` implies you think that `ctx.member` exists too. If `ctx.member` doesn't exist, then `ctx.member.X` can't exist either. Considering `ctx.member` is not a thing, `ctx.member.id/.name/.mention` aren't either.

Comment: All my commands have it, and I'm using it. **IM LITTERALLY** using ctx.respond.

Comment: @stijdnci I apologize I'm using a wrapper for python called pycord, that might be why it works for me.

Comment: Yes, that is why it works for you. Pycord is a fork of dpy that does things very differently, and OP hasn't mentioned that they're using that. There's no real reason to use (or "highly recommend") it though, it can't do anything dpy can't do. Why do you highly recommend it over discord.py?

Comment: It's hard to explain, it works better for my host essentially.